# Struggling to filter by category properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Loading from "./Loading";

function App() {
    const url = "https://course-api.com/react-tabs-project";
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    
    async function setCompany(companyName) {
        await getData();
        const newData = data.filter((info) => info.company === companyName);
        setData(newData);
    }

    async function getData() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const data = await response.json();
            setData(data);
            setLoading(false);
        } catch (err) {
            setLoading(false);
            console.error(`ERROR  ==> ${err}`);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    if (loading) {
        return <Loading></Loading>; // simple loading screen
    }
    return (
        <main>
            <div className="top-wrapper">
                <h2>Experience</h2>
                <div className="underline"></div>
            </div>
            {data.map((item) => {
                const { id, order, title, dates, duties, company } = item;
                return (
                    <article key={id}>
                        <h3>{title}</h3>
                        <span className="company">{company}</span>
                        <p>{dates}</p>
                        <ul>
                            {duties.map((duty, index) => {
                                return <li key={index}>{duty}</li>;
                            })}
                        </ul>
                        <button>MORE INFO</button>
                    </article>
                );
            })}
            <div className="nav-buttons">
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                        setCompany("TOMMY");
                    }}
                    className="nav-btn"
                >
                    TOMMY
                </button>
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                        setCompany("BIGDROP");
                    }}
                    className="nav-btn"
                >
                    BIGDROP
                </button>
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                        setCompany("CUKER");
                    }}
                    className="nav-btn"
                >
                    CUKER
                </button>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Sooo... basically I'm trying to filter the array returned by **Fetch** and have it display only the category I want (I called it "company instead of category in my code") depending on which button I click as shown in the "nav-buttons" div down in the code.
The first time I click on a button it works fine, but the second time it doesn't show anything as if it's **filtering** from an **already filtered array** which return no results obviously.

Comment: I guess its not required to call API every time you click a button here .... also the second time click scenario you explained is not clear tbh

Comment: what happens is that when I click one of the three category buttons the data is set to only the array with the corresponding category, meaning my state value (the data one) is reduced from an array of 3 elements to 1, the next time I click on a button, the getData function only filters 1 array instead of 3 since the other 2 have been filtered out on the 1st click and in result returns nothing

Comment: added my thoughts and approach as answer please check ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update these two methods with these two lines:

```
async function setCompany(companyName) {
    const response=await getData(); //THIS ONE
    const newData = response.filter((info) => info.company === companyName);
    setData(newData);
}

async function getData() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
        return data;// And THIS ONE
    } catch (err) {
        setLoading(false);
        console.error(`ERROR  ==> ${err}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: calling the same API is unnecessary here as the `data` doesn't change on each call ...

Comment: just to keep it simple for the existing code i've added these line, to make it even better what you can do is get data in useEffect and the keep the data in two different states, one that is going to keep the entire data and second one for the filtered data, other way around is the keep the entire data in 1 state and then in render based on the selection display only filtered.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the oportunity to learn about promises, and you will save so much time. ;)

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
    const url = "https://course-api.com/react-tabs-project";
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState("");

    async function setCompany(companyName) {
        getData();
        const newData = setData(newData);
    }

    function getData(companyName) {
        setCompanyName(companyName);

        fetch(url)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((info) => {
                console.log(info);
                return companyName
                    ? info.filter((info) => info.company == companyName)
                    : info;
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                return setData(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setLoading(false);
                console.error(`ERROR  ==> ${err}`);
            });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <main>
            <div className="top-wrapper">
                <h2>Experience</h2>
                <div className="underline"></div>
            </div>
            {data.map((item) => {
                const { id, order, title, dates, duties, company } = item;
                return (
                    <article key={id}>
                        <h3>{title}</h3>
                        <span className="company">{company}</span>
                        <p>{dates}</p>
                        <ul>
                            {duties.map((duty, index) => {
                                return <li key={index}>{duty}</li>;
                            })}
                        </ul>
                        <button>MORE INFO</button>
                    </article>
                );
            })}
            <div className="nav-buttons">
                <button
                    onClick={() => getData("TOMMY")}
                    className="nav-btn"
                >
                    TOMMY
                </button>
                <button
                    onClick={() => getData("BIGDROP")}
                    className="nav-btn"
                >
                    BIGDROP
                </button>
                <button
                    onClick={() => getData("CUKER")}
                    className="nav-btn"
                >
                    CUKER
                </button>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thought about doing something like this but ended up using async await instead but it didn't work, thank u

Answer (score 0):

- you don't need to call the same API on each filter as it returns same data if I'm not wrong.
- you can filter the data with the derived state, by storing the selected company in state i.e., on each render it calculates based on the selected company.
- use the filtered data to render finally.

Here is the full e.g.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Loading from "./Loading";

function App() {
  const url = "https://course-api.com/react-tabs-project";
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCompany, setSelectedCompany] = useState("");  // store the company on click

  const filteredData = selectedCompany ? data.filter(info=> info.company === selectedCompany) : data;  // filter data based on selected company
  
  async function getData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.error(`ERROR  ==> ${err}`);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading></Loading>; // simple loading screen
  }
  return (
    <main>
      <div className="top-wrapper">
        <h2>Experience</h2>
        <div className="underline"></div>
      </div>
      {filteredData.map((item) => {
        const { id, order, title, dates, duties, company } = item;
        return (
          <article key={id}>
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <span className="company">{company}</span>
            <p>{dates}</p>
            <ul>
              {duties.map((duty, index) => {
                return <li key={index}>{duty}</li>;
              })}
            </ul>
            <button>MORE INFO</button>
          </article>
        );
      })}
      <div className="nav-buttons">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setSelectedCompany("TOMMY");
          }}
          className="nav-btn"
        >
          TOMMY
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setSelectedCompany("BIGDROP");
          }}
          className="nav-btn"
        >
          BIGDROP
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setSelectedCompany("CUKER");
          }}
          className="nav-btn"
        >
          CUKER
        </button>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: No worries, The accepted answer calls API on each click, which I feel is not necessary - my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

try putting a check case before filter to insure that your array isn't empty.

```
 async function setCompany(companyName) {
        await getData();
        {data ? 
          const newData = data.filter((info) => info.company === companyName);
         :
        null}
        setData(newData);
    }
```

I think part of your issue is when your calling get data on button click your state isn't set before running the filter logic. I would look over your functional logic and ask yourself is this the best way to do this and am i trying to filter before or after my response.